# _tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories - This probably means that Tcl wasn't installed properly

Tags: python-2.7, tcl, snapcraft

When trying to run my newly created snap (ubuntu 18.04, snapcraft version 2.42.1+18.4) I get the following error:

```
(process:26716): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:29:57.640: Locale not supported by C library.
    Using the fallback 'C' locale.
Gtk-Message: 12:29:57.673: Failed to load module "gail"
Gtk-Message: 12:29:57.674: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"
Gtk-Message: 12:29:57.703: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/snap/facebookbuddy/x7/bin/facebookbuddy", line 16, in 
    root = Tk()
  File "/snap/facebookbuddy/x7/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1822, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories: 
    /usr/share/tcltk/tcl8.6 /snap/facebookbuddy/x7/usr/lib/tcl8.6 /snap/facebookbuddy/x7/lib/tcl8.6 /snap/facebookbuddy/x7/usr/library /snap/facebookbuddy/x7/library /snap/facebookbuddy/x7/tcl8.6.8/library /snap/facebookbuddy/tcl8.6.8/library

This probably means that Tcl wasn't installed properly.
```

but running *locate* tells me something different!

```
$ locate init.tcl
/usr/lib/blt2.5/init.tcl
/usr/share/tcltk/tcl8.6/init.tcl
```

the relevant part inside my `snapcraft.yaml` looks like:

```yaml
parts:
  fbuddy:
    source: .
    plugin: python 
    python-version: python2
    requirements: requirements.txt
    stage-packages: [libc6, zlib1g, cron, python-setuptools, python-gobject-2, python-notify, python-pip, python-tk, python-six, python-lxml]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The file `/usr/lib/blt2.5/init.tcl` is irrelevant. It just happens to have the same name.